# django nginx not serving static files

Tags: django, nginx, django-rest-framework, gunicorn

I am depploying django using nginx and gunicorn. When I access the website I get the following errors.

```
 open() "/home/x/aroundu/core/static/static/rest_framework/js/default.js" failed
```

it's accessing static files wrong, because the path should be like this

```
 open() "/home/x/aroundu/core/core/static/rest_framework/js/default.js" failed
```

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location /static/ {
        alias /home/x/aroundu/core/core/static/;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias /home/x/aroundu/core/media/;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
}
```

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')


MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be:

```
location /static/ {
    root /home/x/aroundu/core/core/;
}

location /media/ {
    root /home/x/aroundu/core/;
}
```

Also for static you have /core/core/ and for media you have only /core/. I don't know which is the right one, but given your settings they should be the same.

Comment: i tried that, same error no changes. maybe i am restarting the server wrong way

Comment: try `root` instead of `alias`